# Import File Activity - File Naming Pattern / Wildcards - How far will the default go back in time?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, import, pattern

My question is about wildcards / file name pattern inside automation studio.

When you define a file name pattern inside an import file activity like `FULL_IMPORT_%%Day%%%%Month%%%%Year%%.csv` how will it behave in general and how far will it look back for files?

> My observations (let us assume we have the 6th september 2018 on
>   marketing clouds default timezone):
>
> - SFMC will look for a file named `FULL_IMPORT_06082018.csv`
> - If it finds such a file, it will import the file If it does not find such a file,it will try to find a file from the day before
>     (`FULL_IMPORT_05082018.csv`).
> - If it does not find such a file, it will    try to find a file from the day before (`FULL_IMPORT_04082018.csv`).
> - Repeat the step in front

- When will it start to fail?
- Whats the default timespan it will look behind? (I assume it wont try
  to search a file like FULL_IMPORT_24121001.csv)

> (No advanced file import options like "Fail import if file is older
>   than the following number of hours:" set)